# A Mac OS X VPN client that can import a .VPN file

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, network, vpn

I have a .vpn file that I use on Windows with the Shrew Soft VPN Client that has the connection details (excluding the username and password). Is there an equivalent client for Mac OS X that will allow me to take this .vpn file and import it and connect to the VPN?

I have tried a few, such as Cisco's, to no avail unfortunately.

When I look at it in a text editor, I get this (host intentionally removed):

```
n:version:2
n:network-ike-port:500
n:network-mtu-size:1380
n:client-addr-auto:1
n:network-natt-port:4500
n:network-natt-rate:15
n:network-frag-size:540
n:network-dpd-enable:1
n:client-banner-enable:0
n:network-notify-enable:1
n:client-wins-used:0
n:client-wins-auto:1
n:client-dns-used:0
n:client-dns-auto:0
n:client-splitdns-used:0
n:client-splitdns-auto:0
n:phase1-dhgroup:2
n:phase1-life-secs:86400
n:phase1-life-kbytes:0
n:vendor-chkpt-enable:1
n:phase2-life-secs:3600
n:phase2-life-kbytes:0
n:policy-nailed:0
n:policy-list-auto:0
n:phase1-keylen:256
n:phase2-keylen:256
s:network-host:80.75.x.x
s:client-auto-mode:disabled
s:client-iface:direct
s:network-natt-mode:enable
s:network-frag-mode:enable
s:auth-method:hybrid-rsa-xauth
s:ident-client-type:ufqdn
s:ident-server-type:any
s:phase1-exchange:main
s:phase1-cipher:auto
s:phase1-hash:auto
s:phase2-transform:auto
s:phase2-hmac:auto
s:ipcomp-transform:disabled
n:phase2-pfsgroup:-1
s:policy-level:auto
s:policy-list-include:172.26.x.x / 255.255.255.0
s:auth-server-cert:crm-gw.cert
b:auth-server-cert-data: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
```

Comment: Does this VPN use a standard protocol or is it proprietary?  The .vpn file extension is not a standard.  You have not provided enough information.  For example, tf this was an standard IPsec VPN, for example and you had your connection information (host, port, protocol) as well as the login creds (either username and password or keys), you can plug these vals into OpenVPN using Tunnelblick as your frontend.

Comment: The VPN is configured by a third-party, however within the Shrew Soft VPN client on Windows I can see that the "Transport Used" is `NAT-T / IKE | ESP`. Does that make anything any clearer?

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old post, but I have been trying to read a .vpn file as well and none of the posted solutions worked for me. The recommended software were not able to read the file.

In case other people have the same issue, I got it by installing the shrewsoft-vpn-client. Since it is not that straightforward, I am putting the steps I did.

1. Install home-brew and run

   ```
   brew cask install tuntap
   ```

Note: To install and/or use tuntap you may need to enable its kernel extension in System Preferences → Security & Privacy → General

2. Download the file [shrewsoft-vpn-client.rb](https://github.com/yakivy/homebrew-shrewsoft-vpn-client/blob/master/shrewsoft-vpn-client.rb) from Github
3. run

   ```
   brew install --build-from-source /path_to/shrewsoft-vpn-client.rb --without-gui
   sudo /usr/local/sbin/iked
   ```
4. Copy the file file.vpn into .ike/sites without extensions

   ```
   cp /path_to/file.vpn ~/.ike/sites/file
   ```
5. Then, start the VPN by running

   ```
   ikec -r file
   c
   ```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You might find [Viscosity](http://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/) to be the answer. It's my favourite OpenVPN client for the Mac and can certainly import a number of config files. It's free for 30 days an then a reasonable nine bucks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening it with a text editor? The connection details might not be encrypted and might be clear to read and copy.

Comment: I've just added the contents of the file opened with Notepad++. With the "B:auth-server-cert-data" parameter encrypted does this mean I can't take the information from this and load it into a Mac VPN client manually? I have a seperate username and password to enter also, that is not in this file.

Comment: no, if you have a different login than you can use it, the cert is just an ssl cert generates upon first connection.

Answer (score 1):

[VPN Tracker](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/vpntracker/admin-interoperability.html) from Equinux supports a number of auto-config standards. They offer a trial version that is fully-functional, but limited to a three minute connection time, for testing purposes.

Comment: I would only be looking to use this quite infrequently, so i'm looking for a freeware version. If there is a VPN client that will allow me to manually enter this information then great, but I haven't found one as yet.

Comment: What information do you need to enter. What type of VPN appliance are you using? The OS (at least modern versions) has a built-in VPN client for IPSec (including Cisco's version) and PPTP.

Comment: I'm not sure what VPN appliance I am connecting to, how can I obtain this information? The transport is defined as `NAT-T / IKE | ESP` within my Windows VPN client. With a free VPN client I assume it's more complicated than just specifying the IP, username and password.

Comment: To obtain the necessary information I would ask the VPN administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Ipsecuritas is free and works well. Xauth is an issue to Juniper devices, for some reason IPsecuritas seems to be unable to see the peer as xauth compatible.

Since you are using a Shrew config, you could try the Beta for Shrew on Mac at the link below. To be honest, I find it to troublesome (not to mention alot of hoops to go through to get the tap's running) and prefer IPsecuritas.

http://lists.shrew.net/pipermail/vpn-help/2010-November/003223.html