# shrewsoft vpn mac client

Tags: terminal, vpn

My question relates to [the solution posted here in this forum:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304923/270484)

This appears to be the only solution I have found in over a year trying that actually appears to be working, so thanks! However, ...

I believe I have followed each of these steps outlined in the above referenced answer and it appears I may be connected but I can't really tell.

As one can see from the output from terminal below, it appears I am able to stop and restart the shrewsoft-vpn-client. I press "c" as instructed and terminal reports "attached to key daemon..."

How do I know if I am connected? Terminal does not respond to any of the listed commands from 'help'. I can control+c to get the prompt back, stop, restart, and connect and get the "attached to key daemon.." response. How does one reference this connection, if it is a connection?

```
MacBook-Pro:sites Mac$ brew services restart shrewsoft-vpn-client
Stopping `shrewsoft-vpn-client`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `shrewsoft-vpn-client` (label:homebrew.mxcl.shrewsoft-vpn-client)
==> Successfully started `shrewsoft-vpn-client` (label:homebrew.mxcl.shrewsoft-vpn-client)
MacBook-Pro:sites Mac$ ikec -r ryno
VPN Connect, ver 2.2.1 : Copyright 2013 Shrew Soft Inc.
: press the 'h' key for help
: config loaded for site 'ryno'
: attached to key daemon ...
```

Comment: Instead of adding a comment please use the 'edit' link at the bottom of the question to fix any typos etc directly.